# JDBC is there a way to detect if a column has a default?

Tags: java, jdbc

Suppose in my table I had a column defined with a default. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders ( 
...
Created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL)
```

Is there anyway to detect that this column has a default in JDBC?  I see I can detect generated keys for the primary but I don't see how to find this information?

TIA

Comment: I think you can use MetaData for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`DatabaseMetadata.getColumns(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method returns a `ResultSet` that describes the columns of a table.  The `COLUMN_DEF` field of each result gives the default value for the corresponding column of the table, if any.