# ResultSetMetaData getting default value of column

Tags: java

I am Using Oracle database.

I want to get default value assign to column using Java JDBC.

But using `ResultSetMetaData` does not provide any method to get default value of column.

So please tell me any idea.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can get column name and value using ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName and ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel values

Comment: Sir, Their to no way to get default value assign to particular column...?

Comment: Sir, i dont want name of that column, I want default value of that column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run this query

```
Select DATA_DEFAULT from USER_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME ='MyTable' and COLUMN_NAME = 'MyColumn'
```

Comment: Thanks sir, i got, what exactly i want.

Comment: Does this work independently of the database server (e.g. will it work both on PostgreSQL and MySQL)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'getDefaultValue' method on ResultSetMetaData in Java JDBC that I can find.

However the following query works:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_DEFAULT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name='<tablename>' and COLUMN_DEFAULT is not null
```

Connect to the db in question, or similarly with the db name querying master.

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses [`DatabaseMetadata`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) rather than [`ResultSetMetadata`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html), so technically it does not answer the question posed. However, it appears more reliable than a query and still has long-term value for the community at large:

[JDBC is there a way to detect if a column has a default?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636404/5645656)

Example:

```
Connection connection = ...;

DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
try (ResultSet resultSet = databaseMetaData.getColumns(null, null, "MyTable", "MyColumn")) {
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        String defaultValue = resultSet.getString("COLUMN_DEF");
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

below function Returns the default value of a column.
call it on your `ResultSetMetaData`

```
public java.lang.String getDefaultValue(int columnIndex) // or columnName
                                 throws DriverException
```

like `ResultSetMetaData.getDefaultValue(columnNameOrcolumnIndex)`

Comment: That method does not exist.