# Java JDBC Retrieve values from DEFAULTs after an insert

Tags: java, jdbc

Does anyone know of a standard way to retrieve value defined with Defaults in a database when you insert?

These are not primary keys but other columns, the getGeneratedKeys method only returns for auto-increment, but I have other defaults like LastUpdate (date) or CreatedOn (date).

I realize that some databases like MSSQL have an output option or Oracle Return option, but I'm looking for a common way to do it.

Comment: Probably only way is to get the default values for a table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235359/resultsetmetadata-getting-default-value-of-column and then when you insert you know if you are not placing the value there it will be the default.

Comment: Depending on the database and driver you're using, you might actually be able to retrieve all columns using `getGeneratedKeys()`, or you may be able to retrieve them by explicitly specifying the column names or column indexes you want to retrieve in the appropriate `execute` or `prepareStatement` methods.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel No getGeneratedKeys does not work with anything other than an autoinc. I tried it on a bunch of different DBs. Some DBs support things like OUTPUT or RETURNS but it's not universal and the the method to get those out are different. I was looking for a generalized way to do it.

Comment: @sproketboy It definitely does that in Firebird (Jaybird, which I maintain) and PostgreSQL, and maybe others. In some databases using the execute/prepare that accepts `int[]` or `String[]` will also allow you to retrieve explicit columns, not just the auto-increment.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Hmm, I tried PostgreSQL to say return all columns with con.prepareStatement(insertStatement, AllColumnNames) but it only returned the primary string. But thanks for reminding me about Jaybird - I've been meaning to add this to my test server. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the generated key so you can then follow up with a `SELECT allTheFieldsYouCareAbout FROM tableYouJustAddedSomethingTo WHERE unid = generatedKeyYouJustGot`.

Yeah, that's annoying and somewhat dubious from a performance perspective (the primary key is doubtlessly indexed, so not too pricey, but it's still another back-and-forth over TCP or whatever pipe you're using to talk to your database).

It's also the only way that reliably works on all major JDBC drivers.

Comment: Yeah the problem only happens if they generate their primary key (outside of autoinc). In those cases getGeneratedKeys returns nothing so you can't query back.